# probability density vs cumulative distribution for monotonically increasing probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I was thinking about a distribution functions and I realised that I do not really understand density functions. Let's have an experiment when I determine how much food consumption will stop the feeling of hunger (but the experiment does not really matter). The point here is that for too little food (between $0$ and $q_0$ in the picture) the probability of feeling full will be zero, then the probability of feeling full is monotonically rising with the amount of food eaten and from certain amount ($q_1$), the probability of feeling full is 1. I tried to chart the relation between probability of feeling full and amount of food consumed.
[image]

I cannot find what is wrong with this picture but this sure looks like cumulative distribution while by definition above it cannot be as the cumulative probability $P(q\le q_2)=1$ but from the picture $P(q=q_0)=0$ and not 1. On the other hand such function is not well normalised and from that point of view it does not look like a density function either. Maybe the whole problem is wrongly defined but I have no idea how to properly define such a problem.

Where am I doing the error?

Comment: The problem is that this is not a pdf, a pdf has on the x axis values (in this case $q_i$) and on the y-axis the probability on $q_i$. Furthermore, for a pdf the area under the graph must be equal to one, and it this case this certainly not true

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar well, the function does have on x axis the values $q_i$, i do not think that is the problem.  It is not normalisable, i agree. But how to define pdf for such a problem?

Comment: This is not a distribution function at all. At the end you are talking about quantities like $P(q<q_1)$ which I interpret as the probability that the amount of food you eat is less than $q_2.$ This is indeed related to the cumulative  distribution for the amount food you eat. However, your graph--which is the probability of feeling hungry contingent on the amount of food you eat--has precisely nothing to do with the probability you eat a certain amount of food. Your graph only looks like a CDF of something since it is increasing and between zero and one.

Comment: Note that distributions only concern one quantity: the random variable in question. Yours concerns two: the amount you eat and whether or not you feel hungry. What you've graphed is a conditional probability as a function of the variable you're conditioning on.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I probably miswritten but I was thinking about the random variable to be "the amount of food that stops making you feel hungry". A similar type of example would be probability of dying based on velocity with which you hit a concrete wall, where the random variable would be the speed that kills you. How to define such pdf for such problems?

Comment: This is not a CDF. It is a dose-response curve. The dose is the amt of food. The response is the proportion of people hungry with that amt of food. //  If this were for a drug, a clinical trial would focus on roughly the middle third of the curve where the curve is 'almost linear' and try to find the slope and intercept of a regression line that fits data in this region. To the left of the region the drug is not effective enough to be useful. To the right more of the drug has diminishing effect (and possibly bad side effects at far right).

Comment: What you're plotting is a valid thing, but "the speed that kills you" is not a well formed quantity. There are speeds that have high probabilities of killing you and maybe even some speeds that definitely kill you, but "the speed that kills you" is not well defined as a random variable.

Answer (score 1):

As described your function is not a CDF or pdf. If you want to view your function as a CDF, you have to change the language a bit. The CDF of a random variable $X$ is the graph of $P(X \leq x)$. So if your function is a CDF and you plug a value $q$ into your function, you cannot get out something like "the probability of feeling full if I eat $q$ quantity of food," but rather "the probability that some random variable $X$ is $ \leq q$." What is that random variable $X$? Well there is no choice of $X$ consistent with your original wording, but it would be natural to suggest "the amount of food required to feel full." In that case, plugging $q$ into your function gives the probability that one will feel full after eating $q$ quantity of food (which is not the same as the function you defined).

There is no contradiction in the fact that $P(X \leq q_2)=1$ yet $P(X=q_0)=0 \neq 1$. All this says is you are guaranteed to be full if you eat $q_2$ (or more), but you are guaranteed not to be full if you eat $q_0$ (or less). In fact, if $P(X=q)=1$ for any $q \leq q_2$, that would say that the random variable $X$ *always* takes on the value $q$.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question: "What is that random variable $X?$ Well there is no choice of $X$ consistent with your original wording,"

Comment: I am a bit confused: CDF(q) = "the probability that the amount of food required to feel full ≤q" thus the associated PDF: PDF(q) dq would be "the probability that the amount of food required to feel full is between q and q + dq?

Comment: @BruceET I am explaining why the original function is not a CDF of any random variable. The reason I change the interpretation to view it as a CDF is to point out OP's misunderstanding about CDF's (that $P(X\leq q_2)=1$ should imply $P(X=q_0)=1$).

Comment: @leosenko The value of a PDF $f$ at a single point for a continuous random variable cannot be interpreted as a probability. Rather, $\int_a^b f(q) \ dq$ is the probability that $X$ is between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @leosenko I should amend my previous comment. $f(q)$ can sort of be interpreted as a probability in the following way: if $I$ is a small interval of length $\epsilon$ containing $q$, then $P(X \in I) \approx f(q) \cdot \epsilon$.